# PostMethod cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, html, apache, web

i have a problem in httpclient

```
when import the following
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
```

and i want to use the PostMethod i have the following msg. :

```
- PostMethod cannot be resolved to a type
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your jar's are correct with correct version
2. Try HttpPost
3. Can you paste your snippet where you are using Post?